# What are the chances of correctly guessing at least three of five cards?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Picking five cards from a well-shuffled regular deck of cards (52 cards), the chances of correctly guessing all five card (in order) is one in $$\frac{52!}{(52-5)!} \quad \text{or} \quad \frac{52!}{47!}$$

But what are the chances of correctly guessing *at least* three cards correctly?

The guess is made before the cards are revealed.

Comment: 1 minus the chance of guessing 2 or fewer correctly...

Comment: The headline question is misleading - it depends on the rules for guessing. If someone is turning up cards from a pack and I am trying to guess each one as it arrives, I can guarantee at least one hit if I always guess Ace of Spades. When that card arrives, I change my guess to a card which hasn't yet appeared, and then again. Interesting question, I might ask it, what is the expected number of correct guesses with such a strategy?

Comment: Yes, the first is correct. It would be $\frac{1}{P(52,5)}$. You can break the problem into several manageable tasks. One way to do that is finding the probability you get exactly three cards correctly or the chance of getting 4 cards exactly or the chance of getting five correctly.

Comment: @MarkBennet, modified headline now.

Comment: Does the player have to guess the five cards in order without the benefit of seeing any of the cards or does the player get to make his choices one at a time after observing each card as it is revealed.?  Your calculation for correctly guessing all five cards assumes the former.

Comment: @GeoffreyCritzer, good point, I have clarified it now.

Comment: Reverted edit. One chance in n where n < 1 doesn't even make sense.

Answer (score 1):

In this answer I am assuming that the player is obliged to make his guess of the 5 card sequence before any cards are revealed.

Lets assume that the cards are  labeled 1,2,...,52 and that the player's ordered guess is 1,2,3,4,5 ( since this guess is equally likely to be correct as any other guess).

What we want to count is the number of injective functions from {1,2,3,4,5} into {1,2,...,52} that have exactly k fixed points.  Here k will correspond to the exact number of cards guessed correctly by the player.  We must be familiar with inclusion/exclusion.

Here is the Mathematica code that gives the probability that the player guesses exactly k cards correctly for k=0,1,2,3,4,5.

> Table[Binomial[5, j] Sum[Binomial[5 - j, k] FactorialPower[52 - k - j, 5 - j - k] (-1)^k/FactorialPower[52, 5], {k, 0, 5 - j}], {j, 0, 5}]

The exact probabilities are:  $\frac{16649407}{18345600}, \frac{5541121}{62375040}, \frac{6511}{1834560}, \frac{2257}{31187520}, \frac{47}{62375040}, \frac{1}{311875200}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ be a random variable measuring the number of guessed cards. We look for $P(X\geq 3)$.

$\begin{align}
P(X\geq 3)&=P(X=3)+P(X=4)+P(X=5)\\
P(X=5)&=\frac{1}{52}\frac{1}{51}\frac{1}{50}\frac{1}{49}\frac{1}{48}\\
&=\frac{47!}{52!}\\
P(X=4)&=\frac{1}{52}\frac{1}{51}\frac{1}{50}\frac{1}{49}\frac{47}{48}+\frac{1}{52}\frac{1}{51}\frac{1}{50}\frac{48}{49}\frac{1}{48}+\dots+\frac{51}{52}\frac{1}{51}\frac{1}{50}\frac{1}{49}\frac{1}{48}\\
&=\frac{47!}{52!}(51+50+49+48+47)\\
P(X=3)&=\frac{1}{52}\frac{1}{51}\frac{1}{50}\frac{48}{49}\frac{47}{48}+\frac{1}{52}\frac{1}{51}\frac{49}{50}\frac{1}{49}\frac{47}{48}+\dots+\frac{51}{52}\frac{50}{51}\frac{1}{50}\frac{1}{49}\frac{1}{48}\\
&=\frac{47!}{52!}(51\times 50+51\times 49+\dots+49\times48+48\times47)\\
P(X\geq3)&=^*\frac{47!}{52!}(1+\sum_{i=0}^4 51-i+\sum_{i=0}^{3}\sum_{j=i}^3(51-i)(50-j))\\
&=\frac{47!}{52!}(1+245+24005)\\
&=^*\frac{24251}{311875200}\\
&\approx 0.00008
\end{align}$

$=^*$ Using Wolfram Alpha [[1]](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%2051-i%20for%20i%3D0%20to%204), [[2]](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20%28sum%28%20%2851-i%29*%2850-j%29%20%29%20j%3Di%20to%203%20%29%20i%3D0%20to%203) and [[3]](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=47%21%2F52%21*%2824005%2B245%2B1%29)

Comment: Why do think the  P(X = 4)  = (47!/ 52! )* (51+50+49+48+47)  ?    If you calculate the P(X = i) for i = 0,1,2,3,4,5 and then add the probabilities do you get 1?

Comment: For $P(X=4)$ I sumed the probabilities of guessing all but the last one, plus all but the 4th, plus all but the third, and so on.